# Where is Camunda Sprig Boot Starter BOM 2.3.0

Tags: spring-boot, camunda

I've been using `org.camunda.bpm.extension.springboot:camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-bom:2.2.0` for some time. Few other Camunda Spring Boot Maven dependencies were released on 29 Nov 2017 in newer version 2.3.0 (e.g. `camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-root`) but not the BOM.

Does it mean that the Camunda Spring Boot Starter BOM is not maintained going forward and should not be used anymore?

I can't find the `org.camunda.bpm.extension.springboot:camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-bom:2.3.0` in Maven Central or JCenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, when the camunda starter moved from a community extension to an official camunda component, the bom was removed.
I expected that it would become part of the regular camunda-bom, but it seems its not.

I opened issue https://app.camunda.com/jira/browse/CAM-8921 and hope we get it back with 7.9